# How to code a linearly increasing function using `i` and `j` in a nested for loop?

Tags: python, algorithm

How can I create a linearly increase function of `i and`j` in a loop?

```
In [2]: x = []                                                                  

In [3]: for i in range(3): 
   ...:     for j in range(3): 
   ...:         x.append(i*j+i) 
   ...:          
   ...:                                                                         

In [4]: x                                                                       
Out[4]: [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6]
```

i.e. what function inside `append` would produce:

```
In [5]: x
Out[5]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Try putting every value of `i` and `j` in a table next to the output you want for those values. It should be pretty straight-forward to work out the equation from there.

Comment: @Prune Could you please explain what is wrong with this question?

Comment: (1) It's a linear equation you can derive from basic linear algebra; (2) It's solved in a variety of existing questions.

Comment: So you're saying its a bad question because I should already know the answer and because I can find it somewhere else (which I couldn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this by doing `i` * (total values `j` can take, which is 3 here) + `j`

```py
x.append(3 * i + j)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
x = []
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        x.append(i*3+j)

print(x)
```